# UNION ALL of more tables and additional data from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 identical MySQL tables, every one of them has different data but same structure.

I Need to sum their values and I do it this way:

```
SELECT
SUM(alltables.Quantity) AS total_qty,
format(SUM(alltables.eur), 2) as total_eur, 
format(SUM(alltables.eur_80), 2) as total_eur_80, 
format(SUM(alltables.eur)*.12, 2) as detrazioni, 
format(SUM(alltables.eur_80)-(SUM(alltables.eur)*.12), 2) as ricevere
FROM (
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_one WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_two WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_three WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_four WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_five WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017'
) alltables
```

This calculates the statements the customer has to get and the result is just perfect:

[image]

I than made an `adjustment` table with the identical structure where in case of some calculation errors I can add some extra lines to adjust/fix their earnings.

So, here comes my stuck point: I have to make a new sum APART from the above and calculate the `eur_80` field by itself with the same WHERE CLAUSE specifications and I have to sum it to `ricevere` (calculated field in the SELECT statement).

Something like this:

[image]

I've tried with a JOIN but with no luck.

Comment: *"I have 5 identical MySQL tables, "* First thing that comes to mind is 'why'?

Comment: Hahahah - because it's a custom import of Apple, Amazon and other sellers data that comes in in different ways from different source and each has a different "treatment" (ie: different percentages)

Comment: @Mr.Web but couldn't you define a view to union the tables? That should make your live easier.

Comment: @Mr.Web - normalize your setup by combining all imports into **one** table with different indicators for seller. You avoid complex querying with such a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add it in a subselect. Because you want the different displayed separately *and* used in the total, I moved the addition of that column and the formatting to a higher level:

```
SELECT 
  format(andadjust.total_eur, 2) as total_eur, 
  format(andadjust.total_eur_80, 2) as total_eur_80, 
  format(andadjust.detrazioni, 2) as detrazioni, 
  format(andadjust.ricevere, 2) as ricevere,
  format(andadjust.difference, 2) as difference,
  format(andadjust.ricevere + andadjust.difference, 2) as adjustment
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(alltables.Quantity) AS total_qty,
    SUM(alltables.eur) as total_eur, 
    SUM(alltables.eur_80) as total_eur_80, 
    SUM(alltables.eur)*.12 as detrazioni, 
    SUM(alltables.eur_80)-(SUM(alltables.eur)*.12) as ricevere,
    (SELECT sum(eur_80) FROM table_adjustment WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017') as difference
  FROM (
      SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_one WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
      SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_two WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
      SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_three WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
      SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_four WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
      SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_five WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017'
  ) alltables
) andadjust
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that using a join is the correct approach. In this case it would be a `CROSS JOIN` (cartesian product) so we do not need any condition. As the join is applied on two subqueries which both only have one row of sums each, that would still produce only one result row.

```
SELECT 
  total_qty,
  total_eur,
  total_eur_80,
  detrazioni,
  recevere,
  difference,
  (recevere + difference) AS adjustment
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(alltables.Quantity) AS total_qty,
    format(SUM(alltables.eur), 2) as total_eur, 
    format(SUM(alltables.eur_80), 2) as total_eur_80, 
    format(SUM(alltables.eur)*.12, 2) as detrazioni, 
    format(SUM(alltables.eur_80)-(SUM(alltables.eur)*.12), 2) as ricevere
  FROM (
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_one WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_two WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_three WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_four WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017' UNION ALL
    SELECT Quantity, eur, eur_80 FROM table_five WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017'
  ) alltables
) sums_table
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
    SUM(eur_80) AS difference
  FROM adjustment
  WHERE user_id = 849 AND Trimestre_month = '6' AND Trimestre_year = '2017'
) adjustment_table
```

Just so that I can sound paternal once a day and in total ignorance of the reasons for having multiple tables with the same structure, I'd advise to merge the tables into a single one with an enum column to differentiate between the entries. Doing that would simplify above query considerably.